# How to get an older version of the API?

Tags: api

There is a known problem with api v32 when used in tandem with .NET dealing with a particular type cast: ListViewRecordColumn[][] to ListViewRecordColumn[]. To my knowledge there is no permanent fix for this, there is a work around, but the way that I am using this code, that will not work for me.

My question is how to gain access to and use version 31 of the API? OR if someone has a permanent solution for the type cast error, that would also be helpful.

Comment: Hello, Kyle, how are you accessing the API?

Comment: I'm accessing the API as a service reference in visual studios 2010 by pulling the WSDL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've put some notes together on how to handle the 32.0 WSDL in .NET - [Importing the Salesforce Winter 15 Partner API to .NET](http://www.fishofprey.com/2014/10/importing-salesforce-winter-15-partner.html). Essentially you need to modify the XmlArrayItemAttribute to make the typeof ListViewRecordColumn an array.

Failing that, [here is a copy I kept of the v31.0 Partner WSDL](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q1zphdtpvhnds57/partner_31_0.wsdl?dl=0).

A permanent fix would either require [Microsoft to update XSD.exe](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/362727/xsd-exe-incorrect-class-generated-for-abstract-type-with-derived-types) (unlikely since that bug has been "Closed - Won't fix" since 2008) or Salesforce to modify the Partner API WSDL.

Answer (score -1):

kyle, would manually changing the port address in the the auto-generated WSDL work for you? Change the following line ...

```
<soap:address location="https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/32.0"/>
```

... to ...

```
<soap:address location="https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/31.0"/>
```

Comment: Marty, this worked. Thank you very much for taking the time to answer this for me. The help is much appreciated!

Comment: It seems I was too hasty in my response. While this worked as far as recognizing the wsdl as version 31, because the wsdl was retrieved as version 32 the error with type casting still occurs.