# Salesforce login using dot net code

Tags: soap-api, .net

```
 static async Task<loginResponse> SfLogin()
    {
        Task<loginResponse> lr = sc.loginAsync(null, userName, password + securityToken);
        return await lr;
    }
```

// In the above code, the loginAsync() method is expecting 4 parameters, missing parammeter is "CallOptions". Please help me in this, what should need to pass here.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Without more information, we're not sure how to help you. It may be as simple as `new CallOptions()` or `new sf.CallOptions()`, etc, or it might be more complicated. It depends on the how the code was imported or written. Please read about [ask] and then [edit] your question to include any relevant information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are using the existing example code from the answer given to [.Net Core 2.0 and async/await Usage](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/189947/102). It has the exact same code as the question:

```
static async Task<loginResponse> SfLogin()
{
    loginResponse lr = await sc.loginAsync(null, userName, password + securityToken);
    return lr;
}
```

Attempting to compile it in a .NET Core 3.1 console application project with a Connected Service reference to the Partner API v50.0 WSDL gives the error:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'password' of 'SoapClient.loginAsync(LoginScopeHeader, CallOptions, string, string)'

You can safely ignore the optional [CallOptions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_header_calloptions.htm) header unless you need to define the `client` or `defaultNamespace`. Those are both fairly specialized options which you don't need when just starting out.

---

Reworked example code to complete the `loginAsync` call from a .NET Core 3.1 console application. Note how I change the clients endpoint to the login URL for authentication.

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SFDC;

namespace DotNetCoreConsoleSalesforceLogin
{
    class Program
    {
        static string userName = "";
        static string password = "";
        static string securityToken = "";
        static SoapClient sc;
        static loginResponse lresp;
        static LoginResult lres;
        static LoginScopeHeader lsr = null;
        static string serverUrl;
        static string sessionId;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //sc = new SoapClient();
            var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
            var loginAddress = new EndpointAddress(string.Format("https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/{0:f1}", 50.0));
            sc = new SoapClient(binding, loginAddress);

            Run().Wait();
        }

        static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Run()
        {
            lresp = await SfLogin();
            lres = lresp.result;
            serverUrl = lres.serverUrl;
            sessionId = lres.sessionId;
            Console.WriteLine("Break");

        }

        static async Task<loginResponse> SfLogin()
        {
            CallOptions callOptions = null;
            loginResponse lr = await sc.loginAsync(null, callOptions, userName, password + securityToken);
            return lr;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Note, if you get the error:

> PlatformNotSupportedException: Compiling JScript/CSharp scripts is not supported

It is a [manifestation of a disagreement between Microsoft and the Partner API WSDL](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/55455/102). You will need to manually update the XmlArrayItemAttribute for `ListViewRecordColumn`.

In `References.cs` change

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("columns", typeof(ListViewRecordColumn), IsNullable=false)]
```

to

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("columns", typeof(ListViewRecordColumn[]), IsNullable=false)]
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, this is helping me,

Comment: Hi Daniel, I did above mentioned changes in Reference.cs file, but still I am getting same error System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Compiling JScript/CSharp scripts is not supported'