# Connecting to Salesforce using dot net code

Tags: soap-api, soap

In References.cs change

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("columns", typeof(ListViewRecordColumn), IsNullable=false)]

TO

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("columns", typeof(ListViewRecordColumn[]),IsNullable=false)]

Still I am facing this issue PlatformNotSupportedException: Compiling JScript/CSharp scripts is not supported" after changing the code in Reference.cs file.

Comment: Duplicate of [Salesforce login using dot net code](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/325781/salesforce-login-using-dot-net-code)

Comment: At the moment this question seems like it may be more about C# syntax and tooling than about Salesforce. It's not clear that it fits within this site's scope and general expertise.